# Inno Setup append rows in a multi-string key in registry

Tags: windows, registry, inno-setup

I need to add some rows in a multi-string value of `PreshutdownOrder` key of Windows registry.

How can I append rows to an existing value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an entry to [`[Registry]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection) with [`ValueType` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection&anchor=ValueType) set to `multisz`. Use `{olddata}` and `{break}` tokens in the [`ValueData` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection&anchor=ValueData):

> On a `string`, `expandsz`, or `multisz` type value, you may use a special constant called `{olddata}` in this parameter. `{olddata}` is replaced with the previous data of the registry value. The `{olddata}` constant can be useful if you need to append a string to an existing value, for example, `{olddata};{app}`. If the value does not exist or the existing value isn't a string type, the `{olddata}` constant is silently removed. `{olddata}` will also be silently removed if the value being created is a `multisz` type but the existing value is not a multi-string type (i.e. it's REG_SZ or REG_EXPAND_SZ), and vice versa.
>
> On a `multisz` type value, you may use a special constant called `{break}` in this parameter to embed line breaks (nulls).

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control"; ValueType: multisz; \
    ValueName: "PreshutdownOrder"; ValueData: "{olddata}{break}newline"
```